# Place a table in an Ordered List in Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, wikitext

I'm trying to place a table inline in an ordered list in Mediawiki however it breaks my numbering. What I want is

```
1. A1
1.1 B1
1.2 B2
my table
2. A2
```

but what I get is

```
1. A1
1.1 B1
1.2 B2
my table
1. A2
```

Basic markup I'm using is;

```
# A1
## B1
## B2
my table
#A2
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's possible with wikitext, but you can use HTML lists to make the table part of B2:

```
<ol>
<li> A1 <ol>
<li> B1
<li> B2
{|class=wikitable
! Header
|-
| Data
|}
</ol>
<li>A2
</ol>
```

The other thing that can help in situations like this (although not, it seems, this particular one) is the [`value`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#attr-li-value) parameter for list items.

Comment: This is one of the two solutions of https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Q9xbaa4rctdx3vn1

Answer (score 2):

As alternative to [Sam Wilson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880121) you can keep wiki markup for ordered list, but use HTML markup for table instead. To do so you'll need to replace all line breaks within table markup with  HTML comments, like this:

```
# A
# B
## BB
## CC
### <table><!--
--><tr><!--
-- --><td>dawda</td><td>dawd</td><!--
--></tr><!--
--><tr><!--
-- --><td>dawda</td><td>dawd</td><!--
--></tr><!--
--></table>
## EE
## FF
# G
```

Note that [`‎<thead>`‎, `‎<tbody>` and ‎`<tfoot>` are not supported](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables/en#Common_attributes_for_columns,_column_groups_and_row_groups).

Comment: This is one of the two solutions of https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Q9xbaa4rctdx3vn1

Answer (score 1):

Colleague worked out the answer so I thought I'd share it here - simply a tweak to the common.css file

```
}
.list_numbered > ol:first-of-type, .list_numbered > ol ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}
```

Comment: This makes the numbers display correctly, but doesn't actually change the underlying HTML structure — you'll still have two ordered lists. (Not that that's a problem, if it works for you.)

Comment: Not pretty, but it did the job and is only on one page for an internal knowledge base :-)

Comment: This doesn't work any more for me, there's no numbering instance of name "item" in mediawiki css.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Sam's (already fine) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880121/785213):

As mentioned [on the MediaWiki Support desk](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Topic:Q9xbaa4rctdx3vn1&topic_showPostId=tnayl2vpuxgmdadv#flow-post-tnayl2vpuxgmdadv), you can use HTML lists to make the table part of B2:

```
<ol>
  <li> A1
    <ol>
      <li> B1
      <li> B2
{| class=wikitable
 ! Header
 |-
 | Data
 |}
    </ol>
  <li> A2
</ol>
```

The indentation is not required, but adding leading spaces for alignment makes the structure easier to comprehend visually.

Alternatively, you can use an HTML table within the wikitext list. Note that MediaWiki [doesn't currently recognize](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables#Common_attributes_for_columns,_column_groups_and_row_groups) `<thead>` or `<tbody>`, so omit those.

```
# A1
## B1
## B2 <table class=wikitable><tr><th>Header</th></tr><tr><td>Data</td></tr></table>
# A2
```

As noted in [wakalaka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42906173/785213), you can (ab)use HTML comments to spread the table over multiple lines, if you wish.

The complexity of your list versus the complexity of your table will probably dictate which method you choose. A benefit of the latter solution is you can hide the gnarly HTML in a template or subpage and [transclude](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Transclusion) it into the list with the expected alignment, which is not possible with the former (see the screenshot below).

[image: Results of each of the three methods of embedding a table within a list in MediaWiki]

Comment: You can indent the table too, no?

Comment: @wjandrea Indeed, you can indent wikitext tables by any amount of whitespace, it appears. That I didn't is evidence of some superstition I have, since leading whitespace _usually_ starts you into a block of preformatted text ([ref](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting#Text_formatting_markup)). Almost seems like a bug, or behavior that could change later?